# MSSQL Obfuscation of column with XML data

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, obfuscation

I need to obfuscate certain words in around 6000 xml rows. However I'm not sure how to do it exactly, because a simple script won't do the job. Here is an example of a row:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><CONTRACT><IBC IBC_REF="*****" IBC_TYPE="I" TELEPHONE_1="*****" TELEPHONE_2="******" MOBILE_PHONE="******" E_MAIL="*****" SOLICITATION_MAIL="0" ARREARS_MAIL="1" MAIL_REDIRECTED="0" TITLE="Mrs" SURNAME_REGISTERED_NAME="******" FORENAMES="******" SALUTATION="*******"
```

The lines are longer but this is a short example, where I need to obfuscate the *****.

Could I get any advice, I have been thinking about creating a program and export the table to a txt document and then obfuscate it in C#, for example but that sounds like a very long fix.

Comment: Why? What are you trying to protect against? SQL Server permissions are **far** more efficient that obfuscation. So is the available encryption, that can go from single value encryption to full end-to-end encryption. Or you could use data masking, primarily meant to hide sensitive information like credit card numbers from unauthorised readers

Comment: I'd have to point out that by stuffing the data into an XML field instead of using proper columns it's *harder* to protect and control access at the field level.

Comment: Because this is personal data of customers and it will be used on the server 'somehow' and could get exposed.

Comment: In that case you need to use SQL Server's far more secure features, not roll your own. [Dynamic Data Masking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/dynamic-data-masking?view=sql-server-ver15) for example already does what you ask. SQL Server also includes analysers that can find sensitive data in a database and suggest solutions.

Comment: You also need to think what you want to protect against. `this is personal data of customers and it will be used on the server 'somehow' and could get exposed` doesn't say much. DDM will prevent people from just querying the data but won't prevent against disk theft. That's what encryption is for.

Comment: For more sensitive data, where you don't even want the admin to read it, you can use [Always Encrypted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/always-encrypted-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15) - the data is encrypted by the *client* driver, which means only specific applications with specific keys/certificates can read the data

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos DDM is not a secure feature.

Comment: @gotqn neither is obfuscation. That's why I repeat that the OP should think what the *real* threads are. GDPR *doesn't* require encryption. PCI has far more stringent requirements for credit-card numbers. And DDM ensures no data is returned to unauthorised users, unlike hand-rolled obfuscation

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes, it require the personal data to be encrypted at rest. Unless, it is critical for the business not to be.

Comment: @ValeriVladimirov If the goal is not to expose these data in certain conditions - then you can delete the tags on read. If the goal is not to hold these info in the XML at all - just delete the tags.

Comment: @gotqn GDPR has no such requirement. With PCI the best option is to *not* store the credit card number at all

Comment: SQL Server also offers [Transparent Data Encryption](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/transparent-data-encryption?view=sql-server-ver15) - the data is encrypted at rest without modifying the application.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos No point in arguing. It may not have explicit requirement to encrypt the data but to protect it. Using encryption is the best way, but it's up to you. The TDE which you point is good way if you are using Enterprise edition as it is not part of the Standard one till 2019.